# How to declare callable variable in python without typing module?

Tags: python, variables, pylint, callable

Since version 3.9 python supports many native builtin types.
How to declare class variable that can be called in future according to PyLint rules without 'import types'?
In this example PyLint hints a message:
`self.on_show is not callablePylint(E1102:not-callable)`

I can only simply suppress message with a following command above my code line:
pylint: disable-next=not-callable

```py
def my_show(text1: str, text2: str):
    print('my_show', text1, text2)

class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.on_show = None # ???

    def show(self, text1: str, text2: str):
        print('show', text1, text2)
        if (self.on_show):
            # HINT: self.on_show is not callablePylint(E1102:not-callable)
            self.on_show(text1, text2)

A = ClassA()
#A.on_show = my_show
A.show('hello', 'world')
```

Comment: You could use something like `self.on_show: tp.Optional[tp.Callable[[str, str], None]] = None` where `tp` is the `typing` module. I'm just going off of your type signature from `my_show`. See the docs for [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) and [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable).

Comment: @Axe319 That's a fine answer, no need to post as a comment. (Though you can add `on_show: Optional[Callable[[str,str], None]` at the class level to avoid cluttering the definition of `__init__`.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I'd convert it to an answer, but OP has since raised the bar with `"without typing module"` added to the subject.

Comment: I don't think there's any compelling reason *not* to import `typing`, and you can still use a type comment like `self.on_show = None  # type: Optional[Callable[[str, str], None]].